# All data is become NULL when run Update Query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a problem with mysql query update and I think it's so weird. I run **Update** query in my code with `Where` clause in that query. But, when I stop that query all the data in my table become NULL and this is not just in data contain in `Where` clause but in all the table.

This is my code :

```
$book = json_decode($this->input->post('stringify'));

foreach ($book as $row)
{
    $data = array(
              'price' => $row->price,
              'date_modified' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
              'modified_by' => $row->username
           );

    $this->db->where('id', $row->id);
    $this->db->where('book_id', $row->book_id);
    $this->db->update('book_availability', $data);
}
```

I create that query with codeigniter framework. I just want to know why that query update all the data in my table and not just the data in `Where` clause. Maybe server cause that problem or anything possible to cause that. I hope someone could suggest me why it happen. Thanks.

Comment: is `$id` defined?

Comment: Hard to see when i can't see the complete code, but have you : update where id = something

Comment: See the last query by echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: @Ghost yes, of course `$id` was defined

Comment: @AndersKink I edited my questions

Comment: i think some issues in your where clause,check your data which you are passing in where clause using foreach loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can happen if there is no value associated to variables which you are using for where condition

It is always good to validate your data before inserting into database:

```
foreach ($book as $row)
{
  if(isset($row->id) && $row->id != '' && isset($row->book_id) && $row->book_id != '' ) {
    $data = array(
              'price' => $row->price,
              'date_modified' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
              'modified_by' => $row->username
           );

    $this->db->where('id', $row->id);
    $this->db->where('book_id', $row->book_id);
    $this->db->update('book_availability', $data);
   }
}
```

Now DB data will be updated only if you have values for given variables. You can use more validation like checking id if it is numeric (as per your DB structure ) or invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
$this->db->update('mytable', $data, "id = 4");
```

So you can pass your WHERE clause into the update function
What I would recommend is to build up you WHERE clause, assign it to a variable and then give it to the update function as the third parameter.

Hope this helps

Comment: What is the different if I used my code before and I used your code ? Any advantages if I used this ?

Comment: @Antonio Hey man 
It is just a way to make 100% sure that you are updating your records based on the 3 parameters you give it so like you know the table the data and your WHERE clause, so if it still doesn't work your WHERE clause might be wrong

Comment: could I used an array data in third parameters ?

Comment: You could do something like this
$this->db->update('mytable', $data, array('id' => $id));
@Antonio